# talend - output of tReplicate to subjob

Tags: sql, oracle, talend

My planned flow is as follows:

```
                                   subJob1   

                                    /
tOracleInput -> tMap -> tReplicate  --   subJob2 
                                    \
                                   subJob3
```

The idea is to query the DB only once for this big sql view, replicate the output, and pass to subjobs so it can be processed in parallel.  To also give an overview of what the subjob would be doing:

```
componentToCatchOutputFromParent   ->  tMap -> tFileOutput
                                  /
tOracleInput (query from view)
```

What this does is to query the sql view1 (for subjob1, different views for different subjobs) (this is expected to be very light query, the heavy query is the one from parent, so idea is to run the parent's heavy query once and reuse), join this with the output from the parent using an primary-key-foreign-key concept, and output into a file.

The purpose of this is to attempt to speed up the processing of data by minimizing the database calls, and to be able to process the generating of output files in parallel.

This sounds like a plan.  But, I can't get around how to pass the tReplicate output from parent job to subjob? And similarly, how to catch the output from parent on the subjob so that it would be possible to join with tMap?

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write to file you can use the tHashOutput component to write the result set to memory. Then use a tHashInput (link it to the tHashOutput) to read that result set later in the job in a different subjob.

You wouldn't even need to replicate. Just put the tmap output to a tHashOutput, then use 3 different subjobs each with their own tHashInput linked to the tHashOutput component.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you dont require tReplicate after tMap because replication of data can be done in tMap itselt by justing having 2 or 3 flows from tMap.

Now you cant direct pass data flow to subjob. So what you can do here is 
- put the data to some files.
-than use tParalellize and create 3 subjob which read from files and have join with view query. Connect tParalellize componect to all three subjob and you are done.

Second approach you can take is:

In your first job, in tmap, connect all three tOracleInput with view query as lookup and have three flows from tMap based on your join condition.

Hope this helps...